# Count with group by with numpy

Tags: numpy, group-by, count

I have a large list with a shape in excess of (1000000, 200). I would like to count the occurrences of the items in the last column (:, -1). I can do this in pandas with a smaller list;

```
distribution = mylist.groupby('var1').count()
```

However I do not have labels on any of my dimensions. So unsure of how to reference them.

Edit:
print of pandas sample data;

```
            0    1         2   3   4   ...  204 205     206 207    208
0           1    1  Random 1   4  12  ...   8  -14860   0  -5.0000 43.065233
1           1    1  Random 2   3   2  ...   8  -92993  -1  -1.0000 43.057945
2           1    1  Random 3  13   3  ...   8  -62907   1  -2.0000 43.070335
3           1    1  Random 3  13   3  ...   8  -62907  -1  -2.0000 43.070335
4           1    1  Random 4   4   2  ...   8  -38673  -1   0.0000 43.057945
5           1    1    Book 1   3   9  ...   8  -82339  -1   0.0000 43.059402
...       ...  ...       ...  ..  ..  ...  ..     ...  ..      ...       ...
11795132  292    1  Random 5  12   2  ...   8  -69229  -1   0.0000 12.839051
11795133  292    1    Book 2   7  10  ...   8  -60664  -1   0.0000 46.823615
11795134  292    1  Random 2   9   4  ...   8  -78754   1  -2.0000 11.762521
11795135  292    1  Random 2   9   4  ...   8  -78754  -1  -2.0000 11.762521
11795136  292    1  Random 1   7   5  ...   8  -76275  -1   0.0000 41.839286
```

I want a few different counts and summaries so plan to do one at a time with;

```
mylist = input_list.values
mylist = mylist[:, -1]
mylist.astype(int)
```

Expected output;

```
11   2
12   1
41   1
43   6
46   1
```

Comment: Add minimal sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iloc enables you to reference a column without using labels

distribution = input_list.groupby(input_list.iloc[:, -1]).count()